# DHCP scope static routes lost when updating network adapter

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, dhcp

When enabling 'use this connection's DNS suffix in DNS registration' locally on a machine (Server 2012 VM) for dynamic DNS updates, the classless static routes configured from a DHCP scope (from 2008 R2 DC, in a different domain in the forest) are being lost resulting in dropped network connectivity. Disabling then re-enabling the adapter brings it back instantly with the routes and the DNS record is updated as expected. Releasing and renewing also fixes it. The network connectivity is lost indefinitely until manually restarted.

There's nothing in event viewer for system or the network specific logs besides me disabling and re-enabling the adapter. ipconfig /all shows the same output with the correct values for the interface before, during and after the restart of the adapter.

Comment: What is your question? 
Does this happen on every server, or only one? Is it a recurring issue on each server, or does it only happen once after you make the change?

Comment: It's happening on every server in the DHCP scope that's configured for static routes. The connection is still active but we lose management access as it's via one of the static routes in the rule.